# Error loading native library. Not found in any of the possible locations Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, grpc

Am getting this error "Error loading native library. Not found in any of the possible locations Google Cloud grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll" while creating channel in google cloud. can any one help me?

```
  var configValue = getConfiguration("GOOGLE_CREDENTIAL", service);
  GoogleCredential googleCredential =  GoogleCredential.FromJson(jsonData).CreateScoped(PublisherClient.DefaultScopes);
  Channel channel = new Channel(PublisherClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host, googleCredential.ToChannelCredentials());
```

googlecredential is getting evaluated. error is happening here in the channel line.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding grpc.core?

Similar issue here - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/1186